# Canonot resolve file .... in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

How to fix this problem?
I try in fxml file references image file from other package in my project?

[image: issue]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your code (and state the error message), instead of posting a link to a screenshot of it.

Comment: Program works well,without exception.But in fxml file or java class when a try to references image(which are located in the project,over relative path) show this I don't know how to called,message or message- error.